# La cadena de entrada no es la correcta

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mvc

Estoy programando en MVC C# y estoy teniendo este problema:

```
'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'
```

He corroborado en la `BD` y está bien. Por lo que, me gustaría saber si pueden ver el error. Quiero aclarar que tanto el `dni` como el `dnidos` son `Float` en la `BD`. Pero, por algún motivo que desconozco, no está funcionando en el código.

**Solicitud:**

```
public double dniDos { get; set; }

public Solicitud(double dni, string codigo, decimal? monto, string soli,
            DateTime fechaSol, double? valnom, string desc,
            string apellido,
            string nombre,
            string domicilio, string numero,
            string piso, string dpto, string mono, string barrio,
            string zona, string localidad, string provincia,
            int? cp, string tipoDni, string fechaNac, string ocupacion,
            string tel, string cel,
            string email,
            string estadoCivil, string observaciones, 
            string nomdos, double dniDos, 
            string codagencia, string codCobrador, string cobdom,
            string ase, int cuo)
            {
            this.DniNumero = dni;
            this.Codigo = codigo;
            this.Monto = monto;
            this.Solicitudes = soli;
            this.fechaSol = fechaSol;
            this.ValNom = valnom;
            this.DescPlanActual = desc;
            this.Apellido = apellido;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Domicilio = domicilio;
            this.Numero = numero;
            this.Piso = piso;
            this.Dpto = dpto;
            this.Mono = mono;
            this.Barrio = barrio;
            this.acidzona = zona;
            this.Localidad = localidad;
            this.Provincia = provincia;
            this.CodigoPostal = cp;
            this.DniTipo = tipoDni;
            this.fechaNac=fechaNac;
            this.ocupacion = ocupacion;
            this.Telefono = tel;
            this.Celular = cel;
            this.email=email;
            this.estadoCivil=estadoCivil;
            this.observaciones = observaciones;
            this.nomDos = nomdos;
            this.dniDos = dniDos;
            this.agenciaCodigo = codagencia;
            this.codCobrador = codCobrador;
            this.cobDomicilio = cobdom;
            this.asesor = ase;
            this.cantCuo = cuo;
        }
```

**Conexión:**

```
public List<Solicitud> cargarDatosPDF(string sol)
        {
            List<Solicitud> salida = new List<Solicitud>();
            string con = "Data Source = dasdasd; Initial Catalog = ProvidusWeb; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = id; Password = pass";
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT DniNumero, codigo, monto, solicitud, " +
                    "FechaSolicitud, valnom, DescPlanActual, " +
                    "apellido, " +
                    "nombre, " +
                    "domicilio, numero," +
                    "piso, dpto, mono, barrio, " +
                    "acidzona, localidad, provincia, " +
                    "codigopostal, dnitipo, FechaNacimiento, ocupacion, " +
                    "telefono, celular, " + 
                    "mail, " +
                    "EstadoCivil, Observaciones, " +
                    "NomSegundoSus, DNIsegundoSus, " +
                    "AgenCob, CodCobrador, " +
                    "asesor, ancantcuoplan, " +
                    "CobradorDomicilio " +
                    " FROM V_SolicitudWeb " +
                    " WHERE solicitud = @sol ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sol", sol);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        double dni = Convert.ToDouble(dr["dninumero"]?.ToString());
                        string codigo = dr["codigo"]?.ToString();
                        decimal? monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["monto"]?.ToString());
                        string soli = dr["solicitud"]?.ToString();

                        DateTime fechaSolicitud = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaSolicitud"]?.ToString());
                        double? valnom = Convert.ToDouble(dr["valnom"]?.ToString());
                        string desc = dr["descplanactual"]?.ToString();

                        string apellido = dr["apellido"]?.ToString();

                        string nombre = dr["nombre"]?.ToString();

                        string domicilio = dr["domicilio"]?.ToString();
                        string numero = dr["numero"]?.ToString();

                        string piso = dr["piso"]?.ToString();
                        string dpto = dr["dpto"]?.ToString();
                        string mono = dr["mono"]?.ToString();
                        string barrio = dr["barrio"]?.ToString();

                        string zona = dr["acidzona"]?.ToString();
                        string localidad = dr["localidad"]?.ToString();
                        string provincia = dr["provincia"]?.ToString();

                        int? cp = Convert.ToInt32(dr["codigopostal"]?.ToString());
                        string dnitipo = dr["dnitipo"]?.ToString();
                        string fechaNac = dr["FechaNacimiento"]?.ToString();
                        string ocupacion = dr["ocupacion"]?.ToString();

                        string tel = dr["telefono"]?.ToString();
                        string cel = dr["celular"]?.ToString();
                        
                        string email = dr["Mail"]?.ToString();

                        string estadoCivil = dr["EstadoCivil"]?.ToString();
                        if (estadoCivil == "C") 
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Casado";
                        } else if (estadoCivil == "S")
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Soltero";
                        }
                        else if (estadoCivil == "V")
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Viudo";
                        }
                        else if (estadoCivil == "D")
                        {
                            estadoCivil = "Divorciado";
                        }

                        string observaciones = dr["Observaciones"]?.ToString();

                        string nomDos = dr["NomSegundoSus"]?.ToString();
                        double dniDos = Convert.ToDouble(dr["DNIsegundoSus"]?.ToString());

                        string codAgencia = dr["AgenCob"]?.ToString();
                        string codCobrador = dr["CodCobrador"]?.ToString();
                        string cobDom = dr["CobradorDomicilio"]?.ToString();

                        string ase = dr["asesor"]?.ToString();

                        int cantidadCuotas = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ancantcuoplan"]?.ToString());
                        
                        Solicitud p = new Solicitud(dni, codigo,monto, soli,
                            fechaSolicitud, valnom, desc, 
                            apellido,
                            nombre,
                            domicilio,numero,
                            piso, dpto,mono,barrio,
                            zona,localidad,provincia,
                            cp,dnitipo, fechaNac, ocupacion,
                            tel,cel,
                            email, 
                            estadoCivil, observaciones, 
                            nomDos, dniDos, 
                            codAgencia, codCobrador, codCobrador, 
                            ase, cantidadCuotas);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                conexion.Close();
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

El **error** sale en esta línea:

```
double dniDos = Convert.ToDouble(dr["DNIsegundoSus"]?.ToString());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Inspección:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. En el momento que falla inspeccciona `dr["DNIsegundoSus"]?.ToString()` para que corrobores es un dato válido para convertirse. En caso de ser `NULL` considerar que valor será por default (lo "normal" sería 0) ya que donde lo asignas no admite `NULL`( es decir no esta como `double? dniDos`.

Comment: Bien, corroboré y `DNIsegundoSus` es `Float, null`. Realicé la inspección, y sale que no posee un valor y es de tipo string. Añadí la captura a la pregunta @RobertoLeOr

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Debes asignar un valor por default para aquellos escenarios que el valor en su momento que existe o se devuelve en `dr["DNIsegundoSus"]` no corresponde a un valor númerico (ya sea cadena vacia, null o que sea alfanumerico u otros). Por ejemplo que tu consulta SQL en vez de solo `DNIsegundoSus` sea `ISNULL(DNIsegundoSus, 0)` (PD: Pongo 0 -cero numero- ya que en C# lo conviertes a numero; verifica bien si debes devolver **string** o **numero**).

Comment: Muchas gracias, era modificar la consulta como has mencionado. Te agradezco, te un buen día @RobertoLeOr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:**

```
"NomSegundoSus, ISNULL(DNISegundoSus, 0)'DNIDOS', " +
```

Modificar la consulta.

Se debe asignar un valor por default para aquellos escenarios que el valor en su momento que existe o se devuelve en dr["DNIsegundoSus"] no corresponde a un valor númerico (ya sea cadena vacia, null o que sea alfanumerico u otros). Por ejemplo que tu consulta SQL en vez de solo DNIsegundoSus sea ISNULL(DNIsegundoSus, 0)

Comment: Que se realiza con este cambio, seria buena idea se agregara informacion para que la respuesta sea de ayuda a otros usuarios de la comunidad, revisa [answer], saludos.